# Undefined variable: myRoom (View: (stress)

Tags: laravel

So i have a simple drop down list that will display the list of data from my database. However i'm not sure why i keep getting an error. I did something like so:

**ShoppingCart.blade.php**

```
public function getCheckout(Request $request)
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('shop.shopping-cart');
    }

    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $total = $cart->totalPrice;
    $RoomTypes = DB::table('rooms')->select('RoomType')->distinct()->get()->pluck('RoomType');
    $checkIn = $request->input('checkIn');
    $checkOut = $request->input('checkOut');
    $myRoom = $request->input('RoomTypes');

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($checkIn);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($checkOut);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $days = $interval->format('%a');//now do whatever you like with $days

    $total = $days * $cart->totalPrice;

    $post = Order::where('checkIn', '=', $checkIn)
        ->where('checkOut', '=', $checkOut)
        ->get();

    if (count($post) > 1) {
        return redirect()->route('posts.shopping-cart')->with('Sorry this date has been taken');
    } else {
        return view('posts.checkout', [
            'total'     => $total,
            'checkIn'   => $checkIn,
            'checkOut'  => $checkOut,
            'RoomTypes' => $myRoom,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then in my **view:**

```
<select name="RoomType" id="RoomType" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
    <option value="">Room type</option>

    @foreach($RoomTypes as $RoomType)
        <option value="{{$RoomType}}">{{$RoomType}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Web.php

```
 Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
 Route::resource('RoomTypes', 'PostsController');
 Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
 Route::resource('reviews', 'ReviewsController');
 Route::resource('welcome', 'WelcomeController');
```

To sum up, the user will select a room, when they press checkout, the variable `$myRoom` should be passed through to `posts.checkout.php`.

However i cannot even get the page to appear as of the error.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to assign `RoomTypes` to `$RoomTypes` instead of `$myRoom` when you return the view?

Comment: but then i have defined it and assigned it to $myRoom above right ? so the way i am doing it, am i doing it correctly

Comment: @dan this didnt work no

Comment: see edit, i have included my routes which may help

Comment: Which file does it say is causing the error? Are you able to provide a screenshot of the error you're getting?

Comment: posts.checkout.php is correct or posts.checkout.blade.php is correct??

Comment: My error appears in the view, it says undefined variabel $myRoom which is in my view

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ambiguity in your question but as the code stands right now you have these current issues:

1. You can't define `$myRoom` and then send it as `'RoomTypes'` to the view (which is currently called `posts.checkout.php` for some reason?!),

    you should send identical names to the view `'RoomTypes' => $myRoom,` should be `'myRoom' => $myRoom`
2. Now the view you posted will not really work anymore because you changed `$RoomTypes` so in your `@foreach` change the `$RoomTypes` to `$MyRoom` like this:

   ```
   @foreach($MyRoom as $RoomType)
   <option value="{{$RoomType}}">{{$RoomType}}</option>
   @endforeach`
   ```
3. When you have a lot of data passed to the view you should do something like this:

   ```
   $viewShareVars = ['total','checkIn','checkOut','myRoom'];
   return view('posts.checkout',compact($viewShareVars));
   ```

Comment: didnt quite work having changed things around

Comment: don't see how this contribute to the problem...

Comment: see i have tried all of that, do you reckon its something to do with my routing

Comment: If you're still getting the error `Undefined variable: myRoom (View: (stress)` , Then i would suggest to echo\dd your way through the function `getCheckout(Request $request)` , Start with the incoming `$request` and make sure the data is valid and right, Then just before calling the view try to echo\dd the data you're sending to the view.